# let diffrent text in generated overlays always start from the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

I've made a plattform to copmare creativity-techniques with bootstrap 3. 
kreativtechniken.com - today it's just in german but we will expand for sure. But first we have to fix a few bugs.

To get detailed informations, users can click the title of the technique and see all details in an overlay.

This overlay is a simpel script and we let it generate like this:

```
$('#tableToFilter tr').click(function() {
                console.log($(this).children('td'));
                $("#overlay p").html($(this).find('td.hidden-description').html());
            });
```

in the html markup we have something like this:

```
<td><a href="#overlay" class="name">Brainstorming</a></td>
                                    <td class="hidden hidden-description">
<p>
<h1>Brainstorming</h1>
...
```

As you can see, it's working.

Now the problem is if you click on a technique, then scroll down, then close the overlay and open another technique, you'll see not the start of the text! it skips you in the same line like before but with the new text.

That's pretty uncool, users should see always the start of the text by clicking a technique.

What can we do?

Thank you!

Comment: `<td class="hidden hidden-description">` is missing a closing `</td>`

Comment: thanks for your answe, but no, i just not write it here. at the end of the text entry, we've closed the tag width </td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing that I spotted is that Your selector is `$("#overlay p").html(`, but `p` is not a child of overlay, so you will need to use a different selector. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W98B7/)** for an example where `p` has an id.

If this is not the problem, then maybe you can edit the fiddle to show what is happening.